# Upload xml data to umbraco

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I'm new to Umbraco but and I need to find an automated way of deploying content to the Umbraco instances we have. We as developers would like to upload nodes to Umbraco via xml files (so we can check it in).
I was wondering whether there is a way in Umbraco to upload xml data programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a page/controller/surface controller where you can upload your XML file, then iterate over the XML and create the nodes using Umbraco's [ContentService](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/management/Services/ContentService). You can create the nodes using the [.CreateContent](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/management/Services/ContentService#createcontent-string-name-icontent-parentid-string-contenttypea) method then assign the values to the newly created node, and then [.PublishWithStatus](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/management/Services/ContentService#publishwithstatus-icontent-content-int-userid-0) to publish the new node.